# How to transition without changing the url in ember 1.11

Tags: ember.js

I have a situation where the back button actually causes harm in my application and I seem to remember a solution in ember where I could have a single link-to helper not update the url (but keeping the routes /link-to helpers for other routes working as usual).

Is this still an option/possible in ember 1.11? If so - how? If no - what other options do I have if I need to prevent a single link-to from allowing the user to go back?

```
{{#link-to "foo.bar" bar}}details{{/link-to}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `link-to` helper doesn't pass the `replace` property down to the view itself, the `LinkView` does have a property `replace` which will replace the current route in history instead of just adding it to the history.

### Option 1

Use an action instead of a `link-to`, and use `this.replaceRoute`/`this.replaceWith` instead of `this.transition...`.

### Option 2

Extend the `LinkView` and set `replace: true`, dupe the `link-to` helper code and call it `link-to-replace` and use your extended `LinkView`.

Comment: I'm thinking option 2 is what I'll end up w/ in this example for no particular reason :)